# Redirect from Application Page to ~site/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, application-pages

I have created a Custom Action which appears on "Site Actions" and when you click on it, it opens a modal diaglog which is a Application Page. within this Application Page I want to redirect to ~site/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx. I have tested following but no success.

```
 Response.Redirect("/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx", true);
```

How do I get HttpContext in Application Page.

```
SPUtility.Redirect("~site/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, ???)
```

Comment: `SPUtility.Redirect("~site/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try the following:

```
SPUtility.Redirect("newsbweb.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.Static | SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLayoutsPage | SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLocalizedLayoutsPage, HttpContext.Current);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463664.aspx

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/How%20to%20use%20SPUtility.Redirect.aspx

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx",  false);
```

hope it helps :)

**EDIT**

```
SPUtility.Redirect("newsbweb.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.Static | SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLayoutsPage | SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLocalizedLayoutsPage, HttpContext.Current);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spredirectflags.aspx

That should safely redirect to the custom file within the layouts folder :)

Comment: thank you I have tested both, solutions, first one generates The file '/_layouts/1053/_Layouts/newsbweb.aspx' does not exist second one does not go to the page I want to. I wan to redirect to the page that is silverlight page of creating new site.

Comment: iv ammended the answer, added the wrong one for you lol, pluss i added the _layouts hence why it came out like '/_layouts/1053/_Layouts/newsbweb.aspx' ooops!

Comment: I have solved this by using _layouts/AddGallery.aspx